# Redis memory filled up to 2 GB with Laravel Horizon

Tags: laravel, redis

redis info memory:

```
used_memory_human:1.95G
used_memory_rss_human:1.93G
used_memory_peak_human:2.04G
used_memory_peak_perc:95.63%
```

I use Laravel Horizon and it is the only thing that uses redis.
Now it reached 2GB limit and stay like this

**First question:**
Why there is 2 GB limit and how to increase it? maxmemory set to 0

**Second question:**
I think there not that much jobs pending on Laravel Horizon to fill up 2GB, looks like trimmer or something not working. Jobs are small, not much information stored. There is about 1-2k jobs per hour and maybe pending around 3-4k.

My trim settings from horizon.php:

```
'trim' => [
        'recent' => 60,
        'pending' => 43200,
        'completed' => 60,
        'recent_failed' => 10080,
        'failed' => 10080,
        'monitored' => 10080,
    ],
```

Where to look next? Everithing working so far but I don't like the situation. Once with big batch of jobs we faced allocate memory issue (Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted)